# How to set an app to use its native language?

Tags: applications, languages

Thanks to my phone being rooted, I can use [app settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) to set an app's language without having to change my system language. but is there a way to determine the native language of an app and by default use that?

Comment: Interesting question. The answer would be probably: use invalid locale (e.g. [`zz_ZZ`](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/04/16/android-localization-tips/)) so that the app will fallback to default string resources (`/res/string`).... just a guess, I didn't (and couldn't) try it.

Comment: @AndrewT. good idea, though I wonder how much of the system this would screw up if used globally...